# Rowspan with Bootstrap-table-fixed-columns extension

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a problem with the [fixed-columns extension](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-fixed-columns) of [Bootstrap-Table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table). I'm trying to use a rowspan attribute to have a "3-rows-high" fixed column on the left, followed by a fixed column of 3 rows, but it seems that it doesn't work :

https://jsfiddle.net/Lx87aetc/4/

The goal is to do something with the following architecture :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3"></td>
      ...
    </tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Does anyone have an idea to solve my problem ?

Thank you,
Ed

Comment: I am not able to figure what exactly you want. May be a diagram representation via an image ?

Comment: @Edouardb - if solved, put a self answer and accept it so this SO post marked solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution simply didn't exist, it was a bug, split into 2 bugs :

Firstly, Bootstrap-Table didn't handle correctly the `rowspan` / `colspan` management (some '-' are appended at the end of the rows). Wenzhixin has corrected this: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/commit/468169cde5bdbf2178a9299d288622fe93777aaa

Secondly, the fixed-column extension didn't handly correctly this either, which lead to a "double" bug (some '-' + buggy fixed columns): I corrected the extension bug : https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-fixed-columns/pull/12

Now it's working : https://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/3v7h5erL/3/

It's solving simple situations like this one :

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-fixed-columns="true" data-fixed-number="3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Momentum</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```